# Joomla 4 - View with multiple parents

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I'm trying to setup the router configuration for the first time in Joomla 4 and ran into a problem. I want to show the same item below different parent views. The parent views generate lists with items and for details i want to show the items on the same url, below the parent.

There are three Views a user could add in the menu: Listing, Search and Item.

These URls should be possible to generate:

- /search/item1
- /listing/item1
- /item1

The problem is that i can only generate these urls if i set something like

```
$itemView->setParent($searchView)
```

Or

```
$itemView->setParent($listingView)
```

But i need both, depending on the Menu-Item where the item should be displayed. Without setParent i get URLs like /search/?view=item&id=xx.

I'm happy for any ideas!

Comment: my workaround for now depends on the old router technique

Comment: Please ask all Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.